# Powershell: how to stream, paginate text from very large files?

Tags: powershell, streaming, pagination, large-files, logfiles

I've got some huge log files that I need to view. I don't want to attempt to open them up in an editor, and I'd like to be able to scroll through them in a paginated manner. It seems as if there is an alias for more in powershell but piping to it doesn't do anything and get-help yields only "more."

This seems to me like a totally silly question, but I haven't figured it out yet--how can I get something similar to the unix more command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the Out-Host cmdlet:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Out-Host -Paging
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
get-content file | out-host -Paging
```